# Smoothing polygon boundaries?

Tags: polygon, overlapping-features

I have a kml file with boundary polygon. It has a lot of gaps and overlaps in them. I converted them into shapefile and tried to use smooth and generalization feature tool in a couple of GIS software's like ArcGIS Desktop and Alteryx and didn't get any difference.

How could I smooth it up?

Comment: What exactly is your goal -- simplified boundaries, smoothed boundaries, removed gaps-slivers, etc? Seems like a non-trivial task, needing more detailed explanation. Please edit.

Comment: What Version of ArcGIS do you have?

Comment: 10.2. The data which I have has gaps as well as overlaps . I need to fill in the gaps and remove the overlaps from this layer to make it a uniform layer.

Comment: Can you use programm code in java or python?

Comment: I am also working on a similar project with a polygon layer.  I tried the [Integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000), but received a less than desirable result.

Comment: You might want to try [GRASS v.clean module](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/v.clean.html).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that you really need "smoothing" as it is understood in GIS vocabulary. Removing overlaps and gaps is a topological cleaning action. Only once you have topologically correct feature dataset can you start smoothing (nicer curve) or simplifying (less vertices).

For cleaning a dataset, what I always suggest is to convert your polygons to lines, then revert back from lines to polygons. This way you don't have any remaining gaps or overlaps. Just sliver polygons. (you need an advanced licence for this, but the free [ET geowizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/) tools also include those conversions)

You can then merge the sliver polygons with their neighbours after identification based on their size (which should be small). They can also be identified using the absence of polygon centroid inside them, but this criteria may not work if your original polygons have complex shapes. The [eliminate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005p000000) function can then be used.

If your overlaps/gaps are very small, you can also directly remove them using "[integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002s000000)" . It is not recommended to use it for large errors.

Last but not least, the best way to clean a dataset is [topoloy](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/1112/learn-how-to-create-a-map-topology-in-arcgis101.html), but this is more complicated. I cannot explain all the step in one post, see the help for further details.

Note : for "Eliminate", you need the free ET geowizard, but there is a workaround without. in short, select the pairs of lines from each sliver polygon, get the longest of the two lines, delete it then convert the new set of lines to polygon.